# How to swap the vowels in a sentence using the Math.random() method?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been taking online course in java, just recently took a break from course to make this application. The application asks user to input a sentence, then outputs the same sentence but with all the vowels swapped. I have it set up like this:

```
private static char  [] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}; 
//(no need to worry about y)
```

then I have a method that takes all the vowels from the input sentence adds it to a different array, and adds a space character in replacement of anything that was in the input sentence that was not equal to any of the values of my vowel array. I did this in order to keep the vowels at the same index in the new array. So now I have a array that is the same length as the input sentence; has the same vowels as the input sentence and all at the same index; and also replaces all non - vowel sentence values with a space.

So if the input sentence were:

```
String sentence = "Hey what's up";
```

the output value of the array, that iterates through the sentence would be:

```
[ , e,  ,  ,  ,  , a,  ,  ,  ,  , u,  ]
```

so the index of the vowels are: 1,6,11

is there any way I can randomize the indexes along with the value they belong to? Any ideas on how to swap the vowels in a sentence would be a greatly appreciated! and here is the method that iterates through the input sentence and adds the vowels of that sentence to a new array:

```
public void addVowelArray(String sentence) {
    vowelArray = new char [sentence.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i ++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < vowels.length; x ++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == vowels[x]) {
                vowelArray [i] = sentence.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < everyOtherLetter.length; y ++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == everyOtherLetter[y]) {
                vowelArray[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    //for (int i = 0; i < vowelArray.length; i ++) {
    //System.out.print(vowelArray[i]);
    //}
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(vowelArray));
    System.out.println(vowelArray[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easier way, if I understand your question, is to do

`sentence.replace('a', getOtherRandomVowel ());`

The `getOtherRandomVowel` method could be written as

```
private char getOtherRandomVowel () {

    Character  [] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    List<Character> vl = Arrays.asList(vowels);


    Collections.shuffle(vl);
    return vl.get(0);
}
```

**edit**

based upon your requirements you may want to check that the returned char is not the same as the original char

Comment: Why are you still down voting my questions/answers?

Comment: why on earth do you think I am doing that?  I think it was you that I reported for down voting my answers out of spite.  Now please lets go our separate ways and enjoy the day.  Bye

Comment: I do not fully understand the code presented here, however just to be clear (I know I worded the question in a awful way) I am trying to shuffle the vowels of a sentence that is inputted from the user. Not sure if that's what you did hear. But thank you for bringing the shuffle method to my attention this should fix my problem. cheers

Comment: If you try this code and it does bot address the problem you are having, then please ask for more help